# How to do lookahead properly with LPeg

Tags: lua, lpeg

To match a string starting with `dog`, followed by `cat`(but not consuming `cat`), this works:

```
local lpeg = require 'lpeg'
local str1 = 'dogcat'
local patt1 = lpeg.C(lpeg.P('dog')) * #lpeg.P('cat')
print(lpeg.match(patt1, str1))
```

Output: `dog`

To match a string starting with `dog`, followed with any character sequences, then followed by `cat`(but not consuming it), like the regex lookahead `(dog.+?)(?=cat)`, I tried this:

```
local str2 = 'dog and cat'
local patt2 = lpeg.C(lpeg.P("dog") * lpeg.P(1) ^ 1) * #lpeg.P("cat")
print(lpeg.match(patt2, str2))
```

My expected result is `dog and`, but it returns `nil`.

If I throws away the lookahead part (i.e, using the pattern `lpeg.C(lpeg.P("dog") * lpeg.P(1) ^ 1)`), it can match the whole string successfully. This means `* lpeg.P(1) ^ 1` part matches any character sequence correctly, isn't it?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to negate "cat" at each position in the lookahead that can match:

```
local patt2 = lpeg.C(lpeg.P"dog" * (lpeg.P(1)-lpeg.P"cat") ^ 1) * #lpeg.P"cat"
```

I think it's appropriate to plug the debugger I've been working on ([pegdebug](http://github.com/pkulchenko/pegdebug)), as it helps in cases like this. Here is the output it generates for the original lpeg-expression:

```
+   Exp 1   "d"
 +  Dog 1   "d"
 =  Dog 1-3 "dog"
 +  Separator   4   " "
 =  Separator   4-11    " and cat"
 +  Cat 12  ""
 -  Cat 12
-   Exp 1
```

You can see that the Separator expression "eats" all the characters, including "cat" and there is nothing left to match against `P"cat"`.

The output for the modified expression looks like this:

```
+   Exp 1   "d"
 +  Dog 1   "d"
 =  Dog 1-3 "dog"
 +  Separator   4   " "
 =  Separator   4-8 " and "
 +  Cat 9   "c"
 =  Cat 9-11    "cat"
=   Exp 1-8 "dog and "
/   Dog 1   0   
/   Separator   4   0   
/   Exp 1   1   "dog and "
```

Here is the full script:

```
require 'lpeg'
local peg = require 'pegdebug'
local str2 = 'dog and cat'
local patt2 = lpeg.P(peg.trace { "Exp";
  Exp = lpeg.C(lpeg.V"Dog" * lpeg.V"Separator") * #lpeg.V"Cat";
  Cat = lpeg.P("cat");
  Dog = lpeg.P("dog");
  Separator = (lpeg.P(1) - lpeg.P("cat"))^1;
})
print(lpeg.match(patt2, str2))
```

Comment: Too bad `pegdebug` is not usable with [LPeg.re](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/re.html) w/o source modification to `re.lua`.

Comment: It may be possible with some patching of `match` and other methods in `re`. Patches are welcome ;).

Comment: I'm using a modified version of Lpeg.re with couple of extensions to the original incl. built-in trace support, %1 args, higher-order -> fun'param' and %patt'param' constructs but there is no official repository to propose a PR with these. The modified version works with your `pegdebug.lua` very well. Here is [a gist you can see a diff](https://gist.github.com/wqweto/9624cca7e02ef03c36c7/revisions?diff=split) to the original.

Comment: Interesting; I think it should be possible to hack it in with some patching of `mm.P` access (judging by the entry point being `/ mm.P` in `Grammar` pattern).

Comment: Yes, I did it with a fairly small modification -- back-referencing capture group `T` and calling the trace function *before* wrapping the result in `mm.P`. In `compile` function `T` is passed next to `G` flag they already impl.